# Auto Sequential numbering based on cell criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, numbering

How can I create auto numbering in column A?

I need the numbering in column A to skip any rows that have the Word "TOTAL" in column C but pick right up again in the next rows.

```
      A    TOTAL
1     A    763523
      B    TOTAL
2     D    765067
3     F    735273
      E    TOTAL
4     F    383763
5     C    933743
6     D    394863
      G    TOTAL
7     H    873674
```

Comment: I was able to work out the below formula but it won't number sequentially skipping the blank cells.  It includes the blank rows and then numbers.   =IF(C1<>"TOTAL",COUNTA($B$1:B1)&".","")  This formula skips a cell that has the work TOTAL in it but then instead of place the next number it adds the skipped cell.  Numbers read: 1, 2, blank, 4, blank, blank, 7, 8.  I don't want it to count the blanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell A2, just put `1`; it's the first value and counting itself will give a circular reference warning.

As from cell A3, put the formula:

```
=IF(C3="TOTAL","",COUNTIF($A$1:A2,">0")+1)
```

Basically, this will count all the values above 0 and add 1. Fill this formula down and you should be good :)

Or if you have only `TOTAL` and numbers in column C, then you can use the following in cell A2:

```
=IF(C2="TOTAL","",COUNT($C$1:C2))
```

Comment: Excellent!  It works perfectly!  Thank you so much

Comment: @RebeccaRickey You're welcome :)